# The day of the month

Tags: numbers

I've learned that the 1st to 10th day of the month is always read specially. However, when I converted these by using my computer typing "いちにち、ににち、さんにち、よんにち、ごにち、ろくにち、ななにち、はちにち、きゅうにち、じゅうにち、じゅうよんにち、にじゅうにち、にじゅうよんにち", these converted correctly. Especially, one-letter day expression can only be found when you convert correctly. For example, if you convert "よっか" or "よんにち", you can get a letter "㏣(IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY FOUR)". But, if you input "しにち" or "よにち", the letter is not shown within the candidates. I've learned that when you use generic counter for 1 to 10, you can use either "つ" or "こ". But, when you refer to over 10, You cannot use "つ", only "こ" can be used.

i) I wonder that the 1st to 10th, 14th, 20th and 24th day of the month also can be read as both "か" as "にち".

ii) And I wonder if I use "にち", the meaning is changed.[image]

Comment: I would note that, while it's fine to specify that you'd like a native speaker's opinion, you could be more polite in doing so. Your question is reaching the fairly diverse Japanese Language Stack Exchange community, and it's not clear why a non-native speaker couldn't answer this question well, so it seems quite dismissive to me to simply start your question with "I'm asking a native Japanese speaker". I appreciate your mother tongue may not be English, so this is not intended as a personal criticism; rather, it is meant as advice to bear in mind, to enable you to make the most of JL SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, "にち" is available for every case but "か" is not. "か" is available only for 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,14,20,24 when you refer to a day.

> i) I wonder that the 1st to 10th, 14th, 20th and 24th day of the month also can be read as both "か" as "にち".

Yes! The both are possible. In my sense, when we call a date on calendar "か" sounds more popular than "にち" if it's available (i.e. 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,14,20,24).
The exception is 1日 which sounds "ついたち" or "いちにち". I think ついたち sounds popular when I say "1st May" for example.

Similarly, When we call period of days (e.g. for 2 days), my sense is the same as above. To call 2日間, 3日間, 4日間, ..., ふつかかん, みっかかん, よっかかん, ..., とおかかん, じゅうよっかかん, はつかかん, にじゅうよっかかん sounds more popular than "にち" pattern.
We will never say ついたちかん. Because ついたち especially means the 1st day of the month. It doesn't mean just one day. We call "いちにちじゅう" (1日中) to say "all day long".

Furthermore, when we call the Nth day of summer vacation, the both are possible and "にち" gets popular back compared to the former cases. For example, "夏休み 8日目" (The 8th day of summer vacation) can be called "はちにちめ" as well as "ようかめ". The both sound natural enough.

Comment: In your sense, the "にち" form is available when referring "the 1st to 10th, 14th, 20th, 24th day of the month" or "2 to 10, 14, 20, 24 days", however the special form (e.g. ついたち(the 1st day of the month only)、ふつか、みっか、よっか、・・・、とおか、じゅうよっか、はつか、にじゅよっか) is more popular than "にち" form, right?

Comment: Ah, sorry for making you confused!! Basically "にち" is available for every case. "か" is not. "か" is available only in 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,14,20,24. And if "か" is available, they sound more popular than "にち" in most cases.

Comment: I updated the first part of my answer to add the explanation in the comment.

Comment: Even if "か" is available, "にち" is often used, right? I think your sense this.

Comment: Yes. Basically right!!

Comment: Then, when "ついたち" is available (e.g. 5月 1日), is "いちにち" often used, too?

Comment: I don't have much confidence to conclude that!! But I would say yes. However, "ごがついちにち" (5月1日) sounds awkward a little bit for me. If you want to be like a native, I would suggest to use "ついたち" as well as "か".

Comment: The conclution is: i) "にち" is often used even if "か" is available, and this is not so awkward. ii) "いちにち" is not often but sometimes used even if "ついたち" is available, but this is awkward a little bit. Am I correct?

Comment: This is my sense and it might be different depending on people. The both "ついたち" and "か" sounds more fluent than "にち" for me when we call a day of a month, though "にち" is also often used.